# regexp to match simple markdown

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to figure out the regexp to match all the occurences of `*this kind of strings*`. Two additional rules unfortunately made this thing more complicated than I thought:

1. tagged string should start with `*` followed by non-whitespace character (so `* this one*` should not be matched
2. tagged string should end with non-whitespace followed by `*` followed by whitespace (so `*this one *` and `*this o*ne` should not be matched

I started with simplest regexp `\*\S([^\*]+)?\*` which for my testing string:

`*foo 1 * 2 bar* foo *b* azz *qu **ux*`

matches places in square brackets:

`[*foo 1 *] 2 bar* foo [*b*] azz [*qu *][*ux*]`

and this is what I'd like to achieve:

`[*foo 1 * 2 bar*] foo [*b*] azz [*qu **ux*]`

so 2 problems appear:

- how to express in a regexp a rule from 2. "search till first non-whitespace followed `*` followed by whitespace appears"? positive lookahead?
- how to match whitespace from rule 2. but not include it into result, which `\*\S([^\*]+)?\*\s` would do?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly should happen to input strings like `*1**2*` and `****1*`?

Comment: `[*1**2*]` as `2*` is the first closing one in the string following the rule of "non-whitespace followed by `*` followed by whitespace". Same for second example: `[****1*]`

Comment: So you want to match both entirely?

Comment: yes, these to cases should be matched entirely.

Comment: What is the expected result for `*****foo 1 * 2 bar*`? The whole string or `*foo 1 * 2 bar*`?

Comment: I updated my answer to support both scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*\\S.*?(?<!\\s)\\*(?=\\s|$)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("*foo 1 * 2 bar* foo *b* azz *qu **ux*");
        int i = 1;
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %s%n", i++, matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

***\S** : * followed by a non-whitespace char

**.*?** : consume chars non-greedy.

**(?<!\s)*** : * following non-whitespace char. This is negative look
   behind, which does not consume non-whitespace char.

**(?=\s|$)** : positive lookahead. * should be followed by whitespace or
   end of line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start matching from the *rightmost* `*`, you may use

```
\*(?=[^\s*]).*?(?<=[^\s*])\*(?!\S)
```

To start a match from a left-most `*` (as in ``), remove the `*` from the first lookaround (or replace its pattern with `\S`):

```
\*(?=\S).*?(?<=[^\s*])\*(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/qjNPYn/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/qjNPYn/2). Add `(?s)` at the start or compile with `Pattern.DOTALL` to match texts across lines.

**Details**

- `\*` - a `*` char
- `(?=[^\s*])` - the next char must be a non-whitespace and not a `*`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `(?<=[^\s*])` - the preceding char should be a non-whitespace and not a `*`
- `\*` -  a `*` char
- `(?!\S)` - a whitespace boundary pattern, the next char can be a whitespace, or end of string can be at this location in the string.

In Java:

```
String regex = "\\*(?=[^\\s*]).*?(?<=[^\\s*])\\*(?!\\S)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/k8xsrD/1) regex:

```
\*(?!\s)(.*?)(?<!\s|\*)\*(?=\s|$)
```

> how to express in a regexp a rule from 2. "search till first non-whitespace followed * followed by whitespace appears"? positive lookahead?

You can use a negative lookbehind to match the final asterisk only when it's preceded by a non-whitespace character and a positive lookahead to match the asterisk when it's followed by a whitespace character or the end of the string.

> how to match whitespace from rule 2. but not include it into result, which *\S([^*]+)?*\s would do?

If you want to check if a `pattern` is followed by a character without consuming it you can use a lookahead, e.g. `pattern(?=\s)` will not consume the `\s` as opposed to `pattern\s`.

Answer (score 0):

I used full matches and not the groups and it matched your test string perfect:

```
"(?<=\\s|^)\\*(?:\\S|\\S.*?\\S)\\*(?=\\s)"
```